# Fonts are not showing in font chooser options of netbeans?

Tags: netbeans-7

I am running windows xp and using netbeans 7.1.2 (Build 201204101705).

When i go to change the font in Tools->Options->Font&Colors

It shows just 5 Font options to select

Dialog
Sansserif
Serif
MonoScaped
DialogInput

Other fonts are not showing? Why? What is the error? or how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I found [this bug on the Netbeans` website](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=230536) useful. It seems to be related to the JDK version.

> Jiri Prox 2013-05-30 14:06:29 UTC
>
> Font chooser in Fonts & Colors tab contains only 5 fonts. See the screenshot.
>
> This issue is JDK related, since it happens only with 1.7.0._25
>
> Product Version: NetBeans IDE 7.3.1 (Build 201305291404) Java:
> 1.7.0_25; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 23.25-b01 Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.7.0_25-b13 System: Windows 7 version
> 6.1 running on amd64; Cp1250; en_US (nb) User directory: C:\Users\jprox\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.3.1 Cache directory:
> C:\Users\jprox\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\7.3.1